# Video Specs across iOS Platforms

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video

I've been scouring the web for video specs along the lines of the iOS Human Interface Guidelines for graphics and icons (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1) but the most I can find is a mention in the section on "Media Layer" under "Video Technologies" (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html).

Specifically:

> The video technologies in iOS support the playback of movie files with the .mov, .mp4, .m4v, and .3gp filename extensions and using the following compression standards:
>
> - H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> - H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> - MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats

My question: are these the only options across all platforms? So an H.264 video at 640x480 and 30fps is going to have the same quality on an iPhone with retina or an iPad with non-retina or an iPad mini? Or should we use, say, a 640x1136 video for iPhone 5, a 320x480 video for iPhone 4 (non-retina), and a 2048x1536 video for iPad with retina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That info is out of date. The exact specs depend on the hardware, for example the iPad3 technical specs are [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp647). You have to lookup info for the specific device and see what h.264 profile is supported. The 640x480 baseline was for very old hardware like a iPhone 3G.

Comment: FYI, max iPad screen sizes for H.264 video for recent Ipad devices: The iPad Pro can decode 2732x2048, 64 bit iPads can do 2048x1536, and older 32 bit iPad3/4 devices can decode 1650x1236. Just check for 32 bit vs 64 bit compilation to decide which size to use on various iPad3/4 devices.